# How do you go about becoming a carpenter's apprentice?

Tags: job-search, united-states, skills, apprentice, manual-labor

How do you go about becoming a carpenter's apprentice? Do you have to go through a certain program, or do you find someone on a job site who is offering the position, or is there another way? Although I have seen people offer apprenticeships on job sites, none of them mention class hours, which, as I have read, is necessary for a carpenter's apprentice to take.

Thank you.

Comment: different countries are going to have different processes - could you add a country tag to limit the scope of the question?

Comment: @HorusKol I did.

Comment: You might also try asking over at [woodworking.se]. I'm not completely sure this question would be on-topic there, but they might have more first-hand experience. You could also just find a local carpenter and ask for advice on how to get started.

Comment: You may also be interested in [the Port Townsend school of woodworking](https://www.ptwoodschool.org). Full disclosure, my uncle is one of the instructors, but I am reasonably confident that the school can stand on its own merits (which are many). Last I recall I believe they were in the process to be able to offer scholarships? So you might be able to attend even if you're not a US citizen or wealthy.

Answer (score 8):

The usual way unless you're in the worst of the third World is to go to a technical institute that teaches the trades, then from there start working for a tradesman. So a large portion of your apprenticeship is basically done in the workshops.

Carpentry is a pretty big field, most will eventually specialise depending on what is available in their area, so you have joiners, turners, builders etc,. But the workshops will cover most things.

Answer (score 2):

In most industrialised countries an apprenticeship in the trades, such as carpentry, do not work like they did in medieval times. It almost certainly involves classes and exams. There will be practical experience but it doesn't usually involve just one 'master' who teaches the apprentice everything they know.

If you want to be a carpenter, find a college offering a certified/licensed carpentry course. They will explain everything that you need to become a professional carpenter. Often they will arrange practical experience for you. You don't need to find a 'master' to apprentice with yourself.

In a developing country none of the above will probably apply.

Comment: Any country that is at the 'least developed' stage or higher will actually have a higher focus on trades than academia. We have solid tradesmen here but it's a coin toss if our professors can actually read and write.

Comment: But where do I find the classes? Do I become an apprentice and take the classes separately?

Comment: Like I said in the answer, find the training colleges near your town, and find one that offers professional carpentry courses. Talk to them about what else you need to do apart from take their classes. And like I said in the answer, you don't usually need to find a 'master' to apprentice to for yourself. But without knowing where in the world you are we can't give you a definite answer.

Answer (score 2):

Many places offer apprenticeships and once you get accepted the practical training is mostly at work and the theoretical training that runs in parallel is mostly at college.

This does depend on the country, which several have asked you to specify...

The theoretical traing can be one day a week at college or two or two weeks at work then one week at college - especially around exam time...

Also possible are classes in the evenings after work has finished.

So, day release, block release, evening classes are used - you may find some or all are used.

Finding an apprenticeship, well any job search scheme or even visiting the companies that are relevant.

Best of luck finding one.

Comment: Thank you. I live in the United States. I've heard that you need to take the classes separately from the apprenticrship with the mentor.